# Clientside PostgreSQL Javascript access without serverside part

Tags: javascript, postgresql, client-side

I know that direct access to a database via Javasript is not recommended, since the user would get the database login and thus the ability to manipulate the database.

But in my case, the user cannot see the client-side code, since it's a phonegap app.

Is there a way to do it? And it not, what is a good way to do with a serverside part?

Answer (score 1):

its really not recommened to access database from client-side its not only for security reasons, but what if you changed the database access or upgrade to different database, so you will have to change it in your app which you may not be able to access again after users installed if its mobile app and then you stuck to your database for ever,

so whatever you want to do you can add an action in server-side and depend on your params it will formulate your Query,

for example sending parameter for user=true this will search for users tables, sending parameter for account=true will search in users-accounts tables and so on.